# Flex Spark GridItemRenderer on maximize window

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, width, flex-spark

Here is my problem. I have a s:GridItemRenderer (the spark DataGrid size where I use this, is: 100% x 100%) and here is the function in it:

```
override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
    myLabel.text = width.toString();
}
```

and here is the "myLabel" in it:

```
<s:Label id="myLabel" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="20" paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0"/>
```

SO AND THE PROBLEM IS:

When i drag the side of the window, and resize it everything is fine! myLabel is updating, but sometimes the last column doesn't. BUT when I maximize the window, NOTHING happend, BUT the "width" variable is updated, but the myLabel.text doesn't. (so I try to use this.width too, but it isn't take effects)

Comment: myLabel.text = this.column.width

Comment: myLabel.text = this.column.width.toString(); --->NaN ??? Why?

Comment: I try: this.column.grid.contentWidth, the width is good, BUT the myLabel.text doesn't refresh on maximize